# Why is Mocha ignoring asynchronous function calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am writing automated integration tests with Mocha and Chai. Here is a simplified version of the code I am testing:

```
exports.doSomething = async function (req, res) {
  return executeRequest(req.body)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("then running");
      res.status(200).send(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}
```

And here is what my test file looks like:

```
const { doSomething } = require("../../index");
const { assert } = require("chai");
const { stub } = require("sinon");

const req = { body: { *data* } };
const res = {
  status: stub().returnsThis(),
  send: stub().returnsThis(),
};

it(`Please work`, async () => {
  await doSomething(req, res);
}
```

When that happens, neither the `.then` block nor the `.catch` blocks are entered—`console.log` does not run; `res.send` and `res.status` are never called.

Another interesting note: If I *remove* the `async` from the test call and save the result of `doSomething()` to a variable, it shows as a promise. When I *include* the `async`, the result of `doSomething` is undefined.

I am new to Mocha and have no idea why it seems to be ignoring the asynchronicity of the code.

Comment: [Don't `async` tests need the `done` callback?](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) The docs are your friend!

Comment: Isn't done kind of obsolete when async/await is used?

Comment: Are you stubbing `executeRequest` with sinon in these tests?

Comment: @DaveNewton It also mentions that async and await can be used as usual... Maybe I will try using done.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I am not. I mistakenly wrote "unit tests" instead of "integration tests." I have since updated the post.

Comment: @WiktorZychla True; returning the promise is another option--forgot that.

Comment: @DaveNewton [No they don't need callbacks, if they're `async`](https://mochajs.org/#using-async-await)

Comment: @Bergi Yep, totally forgot that :cringe:

Answer (score 0):

Your `doSomething` implementation is broken, the promise that the `async` function returns will fulfill immediately - before `executeRequest` is done. You should write either

```
exports.doSomething = function (req, res) {
  return executeRequest(req.body)
//^^^^^^
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("then running");
      res.status(200).send(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    })
}
```

or

```
exports.doSomething = async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const response = await executeRequest(req.body);
//                   ^^^^^
    console.log("then running");
    res.status(200).send(response);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
}
```

Only then your test can properly `await` the `doSomething(req, res)` call, and mocha won't prematurely kill the process.

Comment: I have edited my code to match the structure of your first example (I added `return` before the `.then...catch...` block) to no avail—it still does not wait for the promise to resolve, never calls the `console.log`s, etc. Maybe I should add the actual code instead of the simplified example?

Comment: @squidslippers Might help. Does `executeRequest` work otherwise?